# How to understand this Go makefile?

Tags: makefile, go

```
COVERPROFILE=cover.out

default: test

cover:
    go test -coverprofile=$(COVERPROFILE) .
    go tool cover -html=$(COVERPROFILE)
    rm $(COVERPROFILE)

dependencies:
    go get -d .

test:
    go test -i ./...
    go test -v ./...

.PHONY: coverage dependencies test
```

I don't understand this golang makefile. Is there any tutorial for golang makefiles? I searched Google and didn't find any complete one. For example, I don't see any explanation for what is "cover," etc.

Comment: We don't use makefiles in go unless we're trying to be different and make our code more difficult for others to use.  Complain to your software author for complicating things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is just a plain make file and not even well written.

1. running just `make` will execute the commands under `test`
2. `make dependencies` will download all the dependencies of the current packages
3. `make cover` will do coverage testing and output an html file

Answer (score 1):

You can find enough info and documentation on [golang page](http://golang.org/). There is a "search" in upper right corner, inserting "cover" or "-cover" yielded very useful info, such as [this](http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.tools/cmd/cover):

> Cover is a program for analyzing the coverage profiles generated by
>   'go test -coverprofile=cover.out'.
>   Cover is also used by 'go test -cover' to rewrite the source code with
>   annotations to track which parts of each function are executed. It
>   operates on one Go source file at a time, computing approximate basic
>   block information by studying the source. It is thus more portable
>   than binary-rewriting coverage tools, but also a little less capable.
>   For instance, it does not probe inside && and || expressions, and can
>   be mildly confused by single statements with multiple function
>   literals.
>
> For usage information, please see:

```
go help testflag
go tool cover -help
```